# Do something when exactly one option is non-empty

Tags: scala, collections

I want to compute something if exactly one of two options is non-empty. Obviously this could be done by a pattern match, but is there some better way?

```
(o1, o2) match {
  case (Some(o), None) => Some(compute(o))
  case (None, Some(o)) => Some(compute(o))
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
if (o1.isEmpty ^ o2.isEmpty)
  List(o1,o2).flatMap(_.map(x=>Some(compute(x)))).head
else
  None
```

But pattern matching is probably the better way to go.

Comment: Could the 2nd line be perhaps simplified to `List(o1,o2).map(_.map(compute)).head` or `List(o1,o2).flatten.map(compute).headOption` ?

Comment: Or even more radically, to: `if (o1.isEmpty ^ o2.isEmpty) (o1 orElse o2).map(compute) else None` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm liking the "radical" one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to helpful comments from @Suma, I came up with another solutions in addition to the current ones:

Since the inputs are always in the form of `Option(x)`:

```
Iterator(Seq(o1,o2).filter(_!=None))
  .takeWhile(_.length==1)
  .map( x => compute(x.head.get))
  .toSeq.headOption
```

Using iterator also allows for a sequence of values to be passed to the input. The final mapping will be done if and only if one value in the sequence is defined.

Comment: What is the purpose of `filter(a => Option(a).isDefined` - `Option(a)` is always defined unless `a` was `null`. What is the purpose of `reduceOption` when you already know the `temp` has exactly one element? Is not this the same as `headOption`? Also I do not see `compute` used anywhere in the code.

Comment: Much better. I am afraid you cannot do `compute(temp.headOption.flatten)` though, it needs to be `temp.head.map(compute)`.

Comment: @Suma: The compiler does not complain in my IDE though. I did this because for some entries I was getting Some(Some(4)). I am trying not to assume anything about how `compute` works. I would like to with what implementation of `compute` my code breaks.

Comment: Your code does not compile to me with `compute(x: Int): Int` - `compute` expects content of the `Option` as the argument, not the `Option` itself.

Comment: @Suma, will you please take a look at it now? Hopefully it works as expected.

Comment: You should definitely avoid `asInstanceOf` in the pattern match - it is almost never done, use extractors instead -  if unsure how, check some examples. As for "if the inputs are always in the form of Some(x)" - yes, o1 and o2 are always `Option` (sometimes `Some`, sometimes `None`).

Comment: @Suma, yes. I removed those parts of the answer that were not really addressing what the question asked. For some reason, I was trying to make this work with non-Option values too!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by now deleted answer of [pedrofurla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480674/pedrofurla), which was attempting to use `o1 orElse o2 map { compute }`, one possibility is to define `xorElse`, the rest is easy with it:

```
implicit class XorElse[T](o1: Option[T]) {
  def xorElse[A >: T](o2: Option[A]): Option[A] = {
    if (o1.isDefined != o2.isDefined) o1 orElse o2
    else None
  }
}

(o1 xorElse o2).map(compute)
```

Another possibility I have found is using a pattern match, but using `Seq` concatenation so that both cases are handled with the same code. The advantage of this approach is it can be extended to any number of options, it will always evaluate when there is exactly one:

```
  o1.toSeq ++ o2 match {
    case Seq(one) => Some(compute(one))
    case _ => None
  }
```

Comment: With o1=None and o2=Some(4), the top solution does not compile. For it to work, it seems o1 should never be None.

Comment: @jrook You do not use variables of type `None` normally, you use a value `None` and type `Option`. You can test is like this: `o1: Option[Int] = None` or (which I prefer) `o1 = Option.empty[Int]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize a sequence and then flatten

```
Seq(o1, o2).flatten match {
  case Seq(o) => Some(compute(o))
  case _ => None
}
```