# Scala Tuple Option

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-option

If I have Scala tuple Option of the likes:

```
(Some(1), None)
(None, Some(1))
(None, None)
```

And I want always to extract always the "Some" value if it exists, and otherwise get the None. The only way with pattern matching?

Comment: What result do you want from these tuples? What if both are `Some` `(Some(1), Some(2))`?

Comment: @Psidom Due to the nature of my problem It is impossible to have that case. I was wondering if tuples with options had a similar behavior like that of p /\ !p == False.

Comment: The output that you want is still an Option, right?

Comment: @mfirry Yes I do!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do something when exactly one option is non-empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299907/do-something-when-exactly-one-option-is-non-empty)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is this:

```
def oneOf[A](tup: (Option[A], Option[A])) = tup._1.orElse(tup._2)
```

That will return the first option that is defined, or None if neither is.

**Edit:**

Another way to phrase the same thing is

```
def oneOf[A](tup:  (Option[A], Option[A])) = 
   tup match { case (first, second) => first.orElse(second) }
```

It's longer, but perhaps more readable.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
def f(t: (Option[Int], Option[Int])): Option[Int] = t match {
  case (Some(n), _) => Some(n)
  case (_, Some(n)) => Some(n)
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want always to extract always the `Some` value if it exists, and otherwise get the `None`

You can just use `orElse`

```
def orOption[T](p: (Option[T], Option[T])): Option[T] = {
  val (o1, o2) = p
  o1 orElse o2
}
```

However, this does decide what to do if there exists two `Some` values:

```
scala> orOption((Some(1), Some(2)))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

You should probably use pattern matching and then decide what to do if there are two `Some` values, like throw an exception.  Alternatively, consider using a better encoding for the result type than `Option`.